# JSONStore Initialisation failure with error: -11 msg: OPERATION_FAILED_ON_SPECIFIC_DOCUMENT

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

We are currently developing a Cordova app using MobileFirst Foundation 8.0(20170131) which is working perfectly on an x86 Architecture Android devices and AVDs. But when comes to the 64-bit architecture device like Note 5 and Google Pixel we are seeing below error message while initialising the JSONStore API, where it says the libcrypto.so.zip file which is in assets/featurelibs is of 32-bit instead of 64 bit.

Error in Android studio(v2.2.3):

```
    02-11 13:18:43.136 9317-10425/com.mobiInspect E/JSONSTORE: JSONStoreLogger.logError in JSONStoreLogger.java:192 :: error while dispatching action "provision"
                                                           java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/data/com.mobiInspect/no_backup/libcrypto.so.1.0.0" is 32-bit instead of 64-bit
                                                               at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:908)
                                                               at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1505)
                                                               at com.worklight.jsonstore.util.JSONStoreUtil.loadLib(JSONStoreUtil.java:264)
                                                               at com.worklight.jsonstore.api.WLJSONStore.<init>(WLJSONStore.java:71)
                                                               at com.worklight.jsonstore.api.WLJSONStore.getInstance(WLJSONStore.java:273)
                                                               at com.worklight.androidgap.jsonstore.dispatchers.ProvisionActionDispatcher.initializeCollection(ProvisionActionDispatcher.java:149)
                                                               at com.worklight.androidgap.jsonstore.dispatchers.ProvisionActionDispatcher.databaseActionDispatch(ProvisionActionDispatcher.java:139)
                                                               at com.worklight.androidgap.jsonstore.dispatchers.BaseDatabaseActionDispatcher.actionDispatch(BaseDatabaseActionDispatcher.java:36)
                                                               at com.worklight.androidgap.jsonstore.dispatchers.BaseActionDispatcher.dispatch(BaseActionDispatcher.java:90)
                                                               at com.worklight.androidgap.jsonstore.dispatchers.DispatchingPlugin$ActionDispatcherRunnable.run(DispatchingPlugin.java:79)
                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
02-11 13:18:43.148 9317-10425/com.mobiInspect D/JSONSTORE:JSONStoreLogger.logDebug in JSONStoreLogger.java:177 :: os.arch: x86_64
02-11 13:18:43.152 9317-10425/com.mobiInspect D/JSONSTORE: JSONStoreLogger.logDebug in JSONStoreLogger.java:177 :: Extracting zip file: featurelibs/x86/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
02-11 13:18:43.155 9317-9317/com.mobiInspect W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
02-11 13:18:43.264 9317-10425/com.mobiInspect D/JSONSTORE: JSONStoreLogger.logDebug in JSONStoreLogger.java:177 :: Loading library using System.load: /data/user/0/com.mobiInspect/no_backup/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
02-11 13:18:43.269 9317-10425/com.mobiInspect D/JSONSTORE: JSONStoreLogger.logDebug in JSONStoreLogger.java:177 :: com.mobileiron.wrapped is set to false
02-11 13:18:43.281 9317-10425/com.mobiInspect D/JSONSTORE: JSONStoreLogger.logDebug in JSONStoreLogger.java:177 :: Loading library using System.load: /data/user/0/com.mobiInspect/no_backup/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
```

Comment: Are you using any other Cordova plug-ins in addition to those of MobileFirst Foundation? Please update the question with a list of all plug-ins.

Comment: I believe one or several of the 3rd party plugins you've install cause this error. Create a new app with just cordova-plugin-mfp and cordova-plugin-mfp-jsonstore and you will not see this error.

Comment: @Srujan reddy Tried the sample for MFP JSONStore 8.0 provided [here](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/jsonstore/cordova/) and the app works perfectly fine on a 64 bit device. Tried this on Nexus  5X. Please share a sample recreating the issue to further debug.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the renderscript which we are using in our gradelfile. Where this renderscript will import the X86_64 and armv-64a libraries while building an apk.

To solve this issue, we have two options

1) We can remove 64-bit libs from the build, or set abiFilters to package only 32-bit architectures by using below ndk property in build.gradle file:

```
android {
    ....
    defaultConfig {
        ....
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "mips"
        }
    }
}
```

2) Comment out the renderscriptApi and renderscriptEnableMode and repackage the apk.

Comment: Its not solution of this problem as Google is not accepting 32-bit apk any more from Aug 2019.